# Web RTC without Web RTC

Tags: silverlight, audio, rtsp, webrtc

My problem is this...

I have two sites, one acting as an "Admin" site, the other as general "User" site. I need to broadcast live audio from the "Admin" site to all clients of the "User" site. I need to do this with <1 sec of latency.

Some restrictions include:

- No install on "User" machines (the idea being the whole thing sits on the web)
- If there needs to be a 3rd party plugin then Silverlight is preferred<sup>*</sup>

Any help much appreciated here

<sub>*I have tried IceCast with a flash client, IIS Smooth Streaming, Internet radio, all of which give us a latency of >5 secs.</sub>

Comment: There are more factors involved in the latency, such as network, connection quality, availabla bandwidth, etc. The choice of protocol, server and client is just another factor

Comment: I appreciate that ruda, however having tested the aforementioned methods on machines connected through a local network. This leads me to believe I need to totally rethink the tech I'm using..

Comment: That's both good to know and relevant! You should add that to the original question! =)

Comment: Have you tried the WebRTC example at http://apprtc.appspot.com? (Code available from https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/.) Using this with audio elements instead of video might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Flash with a server like Red5? You're generally going to get subsecond latency (though not much less than that), as it's designed for realtime communications. There's a learning curve with Flex and ActionScript, but if you're at all familiar with XAML, you can pick it up from the sample apps that come with Red5 pretty quickly.

Failing that, if there aren't too many clients, you can use one of the two real-time peer-to-peer solutions out there, namely Flash over RTMFP or WebRTC over JSEP/ICE/RTP. If you can ensure that all the clients are using Chrome, then WebRTC is probably your best bet. If you can ensure that they're *not* using Chrome, then Flash is a good choice. The current Flash Pepper client on Chrome is [buggy up the wazoo](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152314) when it comes to audio processing, and no sign of a fix in sight. (It doesn't support echo cancellation, and the volume of the audio goes up and down horribly.) So if you're using Flash, steer clear of recording and broadcasting your audio on Chrome. And I wouldn't recommend either approach if you have more than half a dozen clients - the number of audio streams is gonna overwhelm your "Admin" browser pretty quickly, I think. Better to push that out to something like a Red5 server.

Silverlight is a bad choice for more reasons than I can count. I'm saying this as a guy who spent several years trying to implement a realtime communication solution on Silverlight. Don't do it.